# Plotting time series dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having a really really hard time plotting a time series plot from a data frame python. Please find datatype below.

```
Time_split     datetime64[ns]   
Total_S4_Sig1        float64
```

The time_split column is the X axis and is the time variable. The total s4 is the Y variable and is a float.

```
0      15:21:00
1      15:22:00
2      15:23:00
3      15:24:00
4      15:25:00
5      19:29:00
6      19:30:00
7      19:31:00
8      19:32:00
9      19:33:00
```

Please be advised that the time series will never seconds fraction i.e. it will always be 00 and also the data be continuous i.e. it will be minute wise continuous data.

The data will NOT NECESSARILY start at a whole hour. It could start at any time for example 15:35. I want to create a graph where the X axis major marking will be full hours like 19:00, 21:00, 22:00 and the minor marking should be half the hour i.e. 21:30, 19:30. I do not want the seconds part of the time to be seen as its useless.

What I want it to do is just graph hour and minute in format HH:MM and major markings at whole hours and minor markings at half hours.

```
keydata["Time_split"] = keydata["Time_split"].dt.time
keydata.plot(x='Time_split', y='Total_S4_Sig1')
plt.show()
```

This code leads to such a plot.

[image]

I do not want the seconds to be shown and I want the marking at full hours and minor markings at half hours.

```
keydata["Time_split"] = keydata["Time_split"].dt.time
time_form = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
ax = keydata.plot(x='Time_split', y='Total_S4_Sig1')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(time_form)
plt.show()
```

This code leads to such a plot.

[image]

Please be advised the seconds will always be 00

Comment: Please post what you have tried, what you currently see in your plot, and limit the scope of your question to what you actually want to change about the plot. It's very difficult for us to guess what you have tried, let alone what you're hoping for!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado. Please see the edits. I really need some advice here.

Comment: So the issue is just tick formatting in the plot itself? everything else about the plot is fine?

Comment: If you use `pd.to_timedelta` instead of `pd.to_datetime` does that fix the problem?

Comment: So essentially the problem starts from the line.
df.Time_split = pd.to_datetime(df.Time_split, format = "%H:%M:%S"). If I am to do a print of Time_split right after then. It will add the useless dates as demonstrated in the plots.

Comment: It looks like the argument, format = "%H:%M:%S", is not implemented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213826/discussion-between-chintan-thakrar-and-michael-delgado).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [matplotlib date formatting](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

# plot your data
ax = df.plot.line(x='time', y='values')

# add the date formatter as the x axis tick formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michael. We have made some progress. I converted the datetime object to datetime.dt.time. When I applied the DateFormatter. It just graphed 00:00:00. through out the enire X-axis. Do you see a reason why?

Comment: Your question seems to be specifically about formatting a datetime axis. Can you post code that creates a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you debug?

Comment: Please look at the updates question after like :Final eidts Minimal code. Hope this is better

Comment: A repeatable example should start from scratch. We don't have your data, so it's difficult to know what you're running into. To get better quality answers, I suggest editing your post (not adding to it) to create a clear, consise question specifically about the issue you're seeing. It's very difficult to help as your question currently stands, because my attempts to reproduce your question don't run into this issue.

Comment: Please look at the edit. I hope this helps.@Michael Delgado

Answer (score 0):

The following should address the problems you are facing:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import numpy as np
#testing data
#keydata = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\t',header=None,names=['Time_split','Total_S4_Sig1'])
x = pd.to_datetime(keydata['Time_split'])
y = keydata['Total_S4_Sig1']
# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y,'ok')
# Format xtick labels as hour : minutes
xformatter = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M') 
## Set xtick labels to appear every 1 hours
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=1))
#set minor ticks every 1/2 hour
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(md.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,30],interval=1))

plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am getting the following error.TypeError: 'formatter' must be an instance of matplotlib.ticker.Formatter, not a matplotlib.dates.HourLocator. Please advise.

Comment: this is the line of code I use above your code. It is what I use to plot. ax = keydata.plot(x='Time_split', y='Total_S4_Sig1')

Comment: See the modification.

Comment: Thanks again. TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'. I am getting the following error. I convert the datetime type to a time stamp like so. keydata["Time_split"] = keydata["Time_split"].dt.time. Right before the plotting business begins.

Comment: @chintanthakrar Does the above solution resolve your issue?